# Do not allow call of a subscriber with the same argument twice until the first is done

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, concurrency, beacon

I am currently experimenting with beacons and I want to get the rssi measurements of the beacons in order to trigger an alarm function.

My problem is the following:

> `alarm` function is triggered multiple times once the subscriber is
>   called

What I want:

> **Do not allow `alarm` to execute more than once** with the previous argument. For example if the alarm function is called with argument
>   `'x'` then someone cannot call alarm with `'x'` but can call it with
>   `'y'` in order to avoid multiple pushes to the database.

My code (I am using noble for beacons and firebase for my db):

```
// alarm script

import { config, Device, db, auth, productsRef } from './index';
import * as noble from 'noble';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


var acquiredRef = db.ref('acquired');

function condition(p) {
   // a boolean function that does something


}


function alarm (address) {
  console.log('Alarm!');
  let incident = {
    date : Date(),
    uuid : address,
  }
  db.ref('alarms').push(incident);

}

if (require.main === module) {

  noble.on('stateChange', function (state) {
    if (state === 'poweredOn') noble.startScanning([], true);
    else noble.stopScanning();
  });

  noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {
    peripheral.address = peripheral.address.toUpperCase();

      if (condition(peripheral)) {
          // query
          acquiredRef.orderByChild('uuid').equalTo(peripheral.address).once('value')
            .then(snap => {
              if(snap.val() == null) alarm(peripheral.address);
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      }

  });

}
```

I tried using queues and async-lock without success. It works the first time alarm is called and then has the same behaviour as above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in making sure the alarm function doesn't get called twice (or more) times in a row with the same arguments (in this case just the string 'address') you could just store a variable and compare you most recent argument to your current argument. If the arguments are the same, don't execute the rest of the function.

```
let previousAddress = null;
function alarm (address) {
  if (address === previousAddress) {
    return; // skip
  }
  console.log('Alarm!');
  let incident = {
    date : Date(),
    uuid : address,
  }
  db.ref('alarms').push(incident);
  previousAddress = address; // update previous argument

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to yours.

On my case an simple elapsed time variable did the trick. This is necessary because the discover callback executes multiple times on the same peripheral.

Take a look at it.

```
noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {  

  if (peripheral.advertisement.localName == 'FinishLine') {


      if (lastDetection == null) {
          alert();
      } else {
          if ((Date.now() - lastDetection) / 1000 > 2) {
              alert();
          }
      }
  } 
});
```

Because of the asynchronous firebase call behavior you can not rely on the query. A pause of 2 or more seconds like I did might solve your problem.

Comment: Hello @ctenuta and apologies for the late response, I used your workaround in another application and was very useful, working again multiple pushes of the same item. However the solution given below worked well for my server-side application; I used yours in the client-side app! So since my question was for the serverside app I marked the other solution as accepted. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @bolzano. I see. On my case the beacon stop the advertisement after a while and I don't need to worry about the server. I imagined the same answer like the solution that was accepted, but then I thought that was not the case. Anyway I'm glad to have helped and thank you for upvoting my answer.

Comment: Your contribution was very useful!